# Move base 64 definition of svg image into an external file

Tags: javascript, html, svg, polymer, base64

I have an SVG in a HTML file, which has an image encoded in base 64. Instead of having the full base 64 string in the html file, is there a good way of keeping this it in a different file which I reference in my `<image>` definition within the `<svg>`?

Here is a snippet of the code in question:

```
<svg>
  <image
    y="0"
    x="0"
    id="image3698"
    xlink:href="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkL... [...thousands of  characters...]"
    height="1082.88"
    width="1280"/>
</svg>
```

I've looked into using the `<use>` object for this but it seems like overkill for this task (and I can't get it to function properly).

EDIT: To clarify what I want to achieve (and I am not sure that it is possible) I would like to keep the code structure above, only replacing the `xlink:href=...` line with any code that retrieves a string from a separate file. I would assume this can be done with javascript but I don't know how.

Comment: decode the base64 data, save it as a file and change the xlink:href to point to that new file.

Comment: @RobertLongson I would like not to have to decode the base64 data, but rather simply have the base64 string stored elsewhere.

Comment: Why do you want to keep the image in base64 form? It will be smaller if decoded into a normal jpeg file.

Comment: If you have to keep it as base64 for whatever (weird!) reason. Just save the snippet above as an external SVG file. And just reference it using a regular `<img>` element.  However for the extrenal SVG to work, you'll need to change the `<svg>` tag to `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">`.

Comment: I realise that this is probably a crazy approach to this specific issue. What I would like to be able to do is have any string in a separate file and then reference it somehow in the initial html. I think I am making a mistake in trying to move concepts (such as a string variable) from other programming technologies to HTML.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I have updated the question, let me know if what I'm asking still doesn't make sense.

Comment: I've added an answer to show what the basic approach would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the basic idea of how you could update the base64 attribute at runtime, using base64 data stored in a separate file.  In this case it's dtored in a Javascript object.

*Note this example doen't work due to the fake base64 data.*

```js
base64imgData = {
  'foo': "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkL... [...thousands of  characters...]"
}

// Get a reference to our <image> element
var img = document.getElementById("image3698");

// Update the xlink:href attribute on the element
// Needs to be done a special way because of the attribute's namespace ("xlink:")
xlinkNS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
img.setAttributeNS(xlinkNS, "xlink:href", base64imgData.foo);
```

```html
<svg>
  <image
    y="0"
    x="0"
    id="image3698"
    xlink:href=""
    height="1082.88"
    width="1280"/>
</svg>
```